# Bitstamp old transactions

Tags: api, bitcoin, currency-exchange-rates

Am I getting it wrong or is it only possible to get the transactions of the last minute or the last hour from the bitstamp API?
That is what the documentation says

```
TRANSACTIONS
GET https://www.bitstamp.net/api/transactions/
Params:
    time - time frame for transaction export ("minute" - 1 minute, "hour" - 1 hour). Default: hour.
Returns descending JSON list of transactions. Every transaction (dictionary) contains:
    date - unix timestamp date and time
    tid - transaction id
    price - BTC price
    amount - BTC amount
```

https://www.bitstamp.net/api/

I guess for a full list of trades I have to use another data provider like e.g. `bitcoin charts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitstamp really does not give the possibility to get older transactions, I think.

I will get the whole history from http://bitcoincharts.com/ now...

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same, this is a response from Bitstamp. Though I am having no luck actually getting results back when I add the parameters. If anybody body manages to get it to work, do tell how. Thanks.

You can use our API in order to receive the entire history of all trade transactions on our platform.

GET https://www.bitstamp.net/api/transactions/

Params:

```
offset - skip that many transactions before beginning to return results. Default: 0.

limit - limit result to that many transactions. Default: 100.

sort - sorting by date and time (asc - ascending; desc - descending). Default: desc.
```

Returns descending JSON list of transactions. Every transaction (dictionary) contains:

```
date - unix timestamp date and time

tid - transaction id

price - BTC price

amount - BTC amount
```

If you set sort to asc (ascending) you will first receive 100 of the oldest orders by default.

You can then use offset set to 100 to receive the next set of 100 transactions and you can continue to do so until you are up to date with orders received.

Comment: this is how it worked some time ago... actually the api is not supporting this...